# Laravel: Eloquent 'more than' and 'lesser than'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I want a Database Query like this in query builder:

`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE active = 1 AND published <= '{$now}' LIMIT 5`

What I made:

```
$now = new Carbon;
$feed = Post::where([
        ['active' => 1],
        ['published' => $now]
    ])
    -> take(5)
    -> get()
    -> toArray();
```

But it's like:

`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE active = 1 AND published = '{$now}' LIMIT 5`

How to make `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `<>` and `LIKE` statements with `::where` method?

Comment: Open a manual please, it's easy to find: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use like this `['published','>=',$now]`

```
$now = new Carbon;
$feed = Post::where([
    ['active', '=', '1'],
    ['published','>=',$now]
])
->take(5)
->get()
->toArray();
```

OR use separate where function

```
$now = new Carbon;
$feed = Post::where('active', 1)->where('published','>=', $now)
->take(5)
->get()
->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent

```
  $feed = Post::where('active','=',1)->where('published','<=',$now)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

> ```
> $feed = Post::where('active',1)
> ->where('published','<=',$now)
> ->take(5)
> ->get()
> ->toArray();
> ```

Please see the manual :https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#raw-expressions